# 「ERROR: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\Firebase\Factory' not found」エラーで通知対応ができない

Tags: php, laravel, firebase

現在 "firebase-php" のライブラリを使用してEC2サーバー内でPush通知の対応を行おうとしております。

https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php

こちらインストールを行い、通知確認テストを行おうとしているのですが、以下のエラーログを掃き出し対応できておりません。

```
local.ERROR: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\Firebase\Factory' not found
```

composerを使用してインストールを行ったのですが、`/home/ec2-user/vendor/kreait/firebase-php/src/Firebase` 以外のパスで参照しようとしております。

初歩的な質問かと思いますが、こちら解決方法など教えていただければ助かります。

```
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;
use Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\CloudMessage;

(new Firebase\Factory())
    ->withServiceAccount([
        'type'          => '直接入力',
        'project_id'    => '直接入力',
        'client_id'     => '直接入力',
        'client_email'  => '直接入力',
        'private_key'   => '直接入力',
    ])->createMessaging()
    ->send(
        CloudMessage::withTarget('token', '直接入力' )
            ->withNotification(
                Firebase\Messaging\Notification::create(
                    '通知テスト',
                    'サーバーから送信'
                )
            )
    );
```

コードはこのようにしております。
テストの為IDやトークンは直接入力しております。
お手数とは思いますがよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 実際にどのようにClassを利用しようといているのか再現が取れるコードを記述することは可能ですか？

Comment: エラーメッセージを見たら、namespaceとかuseの問題だと思います。全てのファイルを見せていただけませんか。

Answer (score 0):

```php
(new Firebase\Factory())
```

を

```php
(new Factory())
```

に変更することで、 `use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;` の `Factory` だと認識されるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 試してみたのですが、同じエラーが出力されました。

Comment: まったく同じエラーですか？他にも `Firebase\Factory` と書いてしまっている行があって、そちらの行でエラーになっているということはないでしょうか。

Comment: 同じエラーでした。
テストで実装を行っているため他の行での呼び出しなどは行っておりません。

Comment: `Firebase\Messaging\Notification::create( ...` の行でも、同様のエラーになりそうですが、そのエラーということはないでしょうか？

Comment: (new Factory())、Notification::create(...と修正して試しましたがエラー内容は同じものでした。

Comment: `Notification` の方は `use Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\Notification;` と宣言しておく必要がありますが、その点は大丈夫そうですか？

Comment: use Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\Notification;の宣言を追加いたしましたが、同じエラーが出ている状態です。

Comment: 一度、useで宣言せずに名前空間も含めた名前で記述してみてはどうでしょうか。例えば、`Firebase\Messaging\Notification` と書いているところを `\Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\Notification` にするといった具合に。Firebase関連のクラスを使っているところすべてです。